# Angular 2 - How to add (click) event to dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, angularjs-ng-click

I try to append a div into my page via a function in my component like this :

```
showTile($event: any,id: number){
       $($event.target).append('<div (click)="somefunction(id)"></div>'))
}

somefunction(id :number){ console.log(id) }
```

The div has been appended by somefunction is not handled, in angular js 1.x I used to work with $compile.

Comment: If you're just showing/hiding a div, why not just use *ngIf?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use **jQuery** to affect the DOM tree when your application works with **Angular2**. There is always a way to *avoid* this kind of the anti-pattern.

If I understand properly, you want to append the div on every click on the element. Why don't you create another component for this? In template, use *ngIf directive in order to show/hide additional content and *bind* click event to `@Component`, which will toggle boolean property. Then in **parent component** just use this component as many as you want. If these child components are specific and needs information, which are available in parent component, just `@Input` them. If you want to invoke parent component function, you could use `@Output` in child and then - invoke parent function.

There you can read a lot about this - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Ok i will see this option, thank you

Answer (score -2):

Inside component.html file

```
<div  *ngIf="condition" (click)="dosomething(data)">
<label >Click here </label>
</div>     
//You div will appear only if condition is true
```

Inside component.ts file

```
dosomething(item){
  console.log(item);
  //do something here
}
```

Comment: That's statically added, not dynamically, even when `*ngIf` is used.